# JCrop Cut Half Resolution of Image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3, jcrop

here I am using JCrop as a tool to crop images which will later be used for profile photos.

Previously I tried cropping, for example I wanted to crop an image with a size of 512 x 512. The program ran smoothly, but when I saw the results of the image stored in the image folder, the size was 512 x 256.

How do you keep the height resolution from being cut in half?
Here's the script, I'm using CodeIgniter 3.

EditUser.php (Controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class EditUser extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
  }

  public function upload_crop() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
      $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/foto_profile_pengguna/';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
      $config['max_size'] = 2048; // 2 MB

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);
      if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
          $uploaded_data = $this->upload->data();
          $uploaded_image = $uploaded_data['full_path'];
          $file_name = $uploaded_data['file_name']; // Dapatkan nama file

          // Load gambar
          $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
          $config['source_image'] = $uploaded_image;
          $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
          $config['width'] = 512; // Setel dimensi sesuai keinginan
          $config['height'] = 512;

          $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

          // Tampilkan halaman cropping dengan mengirimkan data yang diperlukan
          $data['uploaded_image'] = base_url('./assets/images/foto_profile_pengguna/' . $uploaded_data['file_name']);
          $data['file_name'] = $file_name; // Kirimkan nama file ke view
          $this->load->view('upload_crop_view', $data);
      } else {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('upload_crop_view', $data);
      }
    } else {
      $this->load->view('upload_crop_view');
    }
  }

  public function crop() {
    $x = $this->input->post('x');
    $y = $this->input->post('y');
    $w = $this->input->post('w');
    $h = $this->input->post('h');
    $file_name = $this->input->post('file_name');

    $image_path = './assets/images/foto_profile_pengguna/' . $file_name;
    $cropped_image_path = './assets/images/foto_profile_pengguna/cropped_' . $file_name;

    // Load gambar menggunakan pustaka CodeIgniter
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $image_path;
    $config['width'] = $w;
    $config['height'] = $h;
    $config['x_axis'] = $x;
    $config['y_axis'] = $y;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->crop();

    redirect('EditUser/upload_crop');
  }
}
```

upload_crop_view.php (Views)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload and Crop Image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            var cropBoxWidth = 512;
            var cropBoxHeight = 512;

            $('#crop-image').Jcrop({
                aspectRatio: 1, // Menjaga aspek rasio persegi
                setSelect: [0, 0, cropBoxWidth, cropBoxHeight], // Area cropping awal
                onSelect: updateCoords
            });
        });

        function updateCoords(c) {
            $('#x').val(c.x);
            $('#y').val(c.y);
            $('#w').val(c.w);
            $('#h').val(c.h);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if (isset($error)) : ?>
        <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $error; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (isset($uploaded_image)) : ?>
    <h2>Upload and Crop Image</h2>
      <form action="<?php echo site_url('EditUser/crop'); ?>" method="post">
          <img src="<?php echo $uploaded_image; ?>" id="crop-image" />
          <input type="text" name="x" id="x">
          <input type="text" name="y" id="y">
          <input type="text" name="w" id="w">
          <input type="text" name="h" id="h">
          <input type="text" name="file_name" value="<?php echo $file_name; ?>">
          <input type="submit" value="Crop">
      </form>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Upload Image</h2>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('EditUser/upload_crop'); ?>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload and Crop" />
        </form>
    <?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope I can get the solution here, thanks a lot

Comment: If you are using jcrop from the client side and cropping of the image is done, why do you need to process the image at the php side?